# Spring Boot Security and setting security.basic.path

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I'm trying to use Spring Boot and it's autoconfiguration future for autoconfigure Spring Security. I follow the tutorial http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/, but I don't want to secure whole apliacation, but only some paths (eg. /secured/**).

I tried set up a path setting in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.Basic via application.properties:

```
security.basic.path=/secure/**
```

but it has no effect at all. Can somebody help?

Comment: If you are following that tutorial setting the `security.basic.path` isn't going to do anything. You will have to modify the configuration you created to match (or not match) the given URLs. The property refers to the default basic security and has no reference to other manually setup security configs.