# Spring Boot Security: security.basic.path

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

What is the purpose of having

```
security.basic.path=/any-secured-path/**
```

this setting in application.properties?

It seems that Basic Auth is not kicking in automatically accessing this url (or suburls).

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060099/spring-boot-security-and-setting-security-basic-path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `security.basic.path` starts after context path. So no matter what the context path is, just set the protected path after that. For example, the full url is `/mycontextpath/pathA/pathB`, if you want to have /pathB to be protected, just set `security.basic.path=/pathA/pathB`. If context path is `/` only, you should still set `security.basic.path=/pathA/pathB`.